# Posts not showing author who wrote it in Django

Tags: python, django

Basically, I'm writing an app in which people can make blog and image posts. So far, I've completed users to be able to write text posts. However, when I try to create a post, it returns "By: None" when it should be returning "By: shrey". In this case, Bob is the author. Here's an image:
[image]

Here's an image for the post creation view:
[image]

Theoretically, when I enter a post it should say who it was written by.
Here's the template for the create post:

```
{% extends "social/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content4 %}
  <h1>Make Your Post</h1>
  <p>Write a post / Share an image</p>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form|crispy}}

      <button type="submit" name="button">Make Post</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock content4 %}
```

Here's the function for the create post view:

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Posts
    fields = ['post_title', 'post_text_content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        print(self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Home Page Template (template which displays the posts):

```
{% extends "social/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Your Feed</h1>
  <p>This is your feed. Here, you'll see posts from people you follow.</p>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>You are logged in as {{user.username}}. This is your feed.</p>
  {% else %}
    <p>You are not logged in. This is a random feed.</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% for post in posts %}
      <h1>{{ post.post_title }}</h1>
      <p>By {{ post.post_author }}  on <i>{{ post.post_date }}</i></p>
      <p>{{ post.post_text_content }}</p>
  {% endfor %}

      <a href="/create">Click here to make a post.</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/logout">Click here to logout.</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/login">Click here to login.</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/register">Click here to sign up and make an account.</a>
  <!--<p>Want to post something? Enter your info here: </p> -->
{% endblock content %}
```

Posts Model:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length = 40, help_text = 'Enter post title')
    post_text_content = models.TextField(max_length = 1000)
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = False)
    #Make optional Image Field

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['post_title', 'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_text_content']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('social-home')
```

Comment: Can you show where you *render* the post, together with the `Posts` model?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: can you show the template where you *display* a post (so with the "By" part).

Comment: Please also add the `Posts` model (so something like `class Posts(models.Model): ...`.

Comment: I added both files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the field is `post_author`, not <s>`author`</s>, hence you should set `post_author`:

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Posts
    fields = ['post_title', 'post_text_content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

That being said, normally in Django one does *not* prefixes the model fields with the name of the model. One reason not to do that is that you can define *abstract* models where you define the field once, and then use inheritance to add the field to other models.